# Identify apple user:subscription pair on a server

Tags: ios, swift

I’m developing IOS app which do calls to the server. I want to allow users to use web services from ios app only after subscription was made, no login required

How to identify whether IOS REST caller have active subscription, without “login with apple” ? I saw several apps is able to do “premium” calls to server right after subscription was made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way:

1. An account ID is automatically created when the app is started for the first time. This happens unnoticeably in the background.
2. The account ID is sent with every API request. The server then only checks whether this account ID has a premium status.
3. If the user buys the premium status, update the account ID on the server side.

This is just a short description without any advice on security and best practices. Please implement this solution only if you know what you are doing. By the way, this approach is also used by ivpn.net.

Comment: How “restore purchase” works it this flow , on a new device installation? Thanks

Comment: I think you misunderstood my answer a bit. Apple doesn't provide a simple API for your case that you can use. You have to solve the problem with your own business logic. For example, you could generate a UUID (again, think about security) and store it in your user's iCloud.

Comment: Thanks, that”s exact answer what i looked for.